# How to enable Code Completion Auto pop-up in WebStorm?

Tags: html, autocomplete, webstorm

I've been trying to get Code Completion to work on the current version of WebStorm (2017.3), but to no avail.

Specifically when working with HTML code completion seems to only work when I press the shortcut `ctrl+space`. As far as I can tell I should be able to get the Code Completion look up table to pop-up automatically when I start typing by going to `Preferences > Editor > General > Code Completion` and checking the box for `Autopopup code completion` the thing is... I DON'T SEE THAT BOX!!!

This is driving me insane. I've looked under Code Completion in [WebStorm 2017.3 Help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/code-completion.html) and there are discrepancies between what the instructions say I should see, and what I actually see.

This is a picture of my Code Completion window in WebStorm 2017.3:

[image]

but it should look more like this (IntelliJ IDE 2017.3):

[image]

The `Basic Completion` box is missing in WebStorm. Not sure if that has something to do with it.

I've looked around and it seems like other people's `Code Completion` window looks like it's supposed to. For example in this [Community Forum](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207004845-QUESTION-WebStorm-Code-Completion-How-to-get-code-completion-to-always-work-) there is a post in 2015 and another in 2016 where the users show their `Code Completion` preferences and they look like they're supposed to.

I've tried re-installing WebStorm, deleting all preferences and the `.plist` but it hasn't worked.

I would like to note, that this issue seems to be affecting only my HTML documents, since the Autocomplete pop-up table for JavaScript works well.

Any ideas on what might be going on? Is there something on my end I can do to fix this?

Comment: preferences look just as they should, and `auto-display code completion` is enabled. Where doesn't the completion work for you? It should auto-popup when you enter `<` or attribute name; it shouldn't auto-popup if you enter tag name without angle brackets

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short: it works as intended.

Thing is: it's HTML context ... where *everything* is a plain text with HTML tags inside (despite the fact that whole HTML document starts with `<html>` tag and stuff).

In this regard HTML context is not that strict/obvious as JavaScript/PHP/etc is. There is no way to guess if you are trying to write a word `strong` or a HTML tag `<strong>` .. hence you see no completion popup when you just typing any word. But .. if you type `<` before starting typing `strong` it will be a hint for IDE that you are typing a HTML tag (which means HTML context)... and completion popup will appear as usual (no need to invoke it manually).

If it would work as you are expecting/proposing (having completion popup for each word) then I would see it for **every word** in `Any ideas on what might be going on?` sentence. It will be supper annoying to see that popup appearing/disappearing for no reason for each word (when I'm clearly typing a plain text). Some people get mad even for much smaller things (like highlighting a matching brace or tag when you move caret left/right)...

Related subject: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000719050-Autopopup-completion-works-inside-php-tag-but-doesn-t-work-outside-of-it-Is-there-any-fix-

---

If typing `<` is a problem (not convenient or any other "religious" reasons (e.g. "why should I type it -- IDE should do that for me" etc)) -- consider speed up even more with [Emmet](https://docs.emmet.io/) (IDE supports basic abbreviations as well as expanding sequences) or [Live Templates](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Live+Templates+%28Snippets%29+in+PhpStorm) (basic Emmet abbreviations are handled with Live Template under the hood anyway).

- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/emmet.html
- https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/live-templates.html

Comment: Thanks for the answer, you make a lot of sense I never thought about it that way.